# How to ask a question requesting criticism of a specific resource?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to ask for general criticism or scrutiny of a book (most searches result in sales), but am unsure how to keep it from being too general. The book makes a handful of claims, and to keep from being too open-ended, should i ask in the form (A) which claims are the most debunked / criticized, or (B) who are the most vocal critics of [book]. or (C) some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on what you want from the book & critique.

1. Ask for a critique of the book's main thesis.
2. Ask for a critique of one specific claim, or a few related claims which can be summarised in one statement.

I think asking for (A) or (B) would be too subjective, though they might be acceptable as community wikis.

Comment: I think those are much better angles. Summarizing the main thesis might be difficult though.